# PDO INSERT query 500 server error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to using PDO and I am getting an http 500 server error when the form is submitted.

The php page with the processing code is in the correct folder so I don't know why its throwing up a 500 error.

There is NO url rewrite going on neither .

Here is my code:

```
        try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=crm",$username,$password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO testdrives (forename, surname,phone,email,add1,add2,add3,city,county,postcode,car,date) VALUES (:forename, :surname,:phone,:email,:add1,:add2,:add3,:city,:county,:postcode,:car,:date)");
                $stmt->bindParam(':forename', $_POST['forename']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':surname', $_POST['surname']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $_POST['phone']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':add1', $_POST['add1']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':add2', $_POST['add2']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':add3', $_POST['add3']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':city', $_POST['city']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':county', $_POST['county']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':postcode', $_POST['postcode']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':car', $_POST['car']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date']);
                $stmt->execute();
        if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
        }
        else{
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
        }

        $dbh = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: `if ($dbh->query($sql))` that shouldn't even be part of your code.

Comment: If there's a 500 error from PHP, there's a log with an actual error - if you just let it, PHP will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: What's the error in your PHP logs?  When you enable error reporting, what do you see?  500 means "an error happened", you need to see what that error actually is.

Comment: u are also using a reserved word

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile what reserved word is that? Not `date` I hope? If so, it's a keyword, not reserved.

Comment: lose this line `if ($dbh->query($sql)) {}` doesn't make any sense..

Comment: you might be getting that error because `$sql` is undifined

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile *"lose this line if ($dbh->query($sql)) {} doesn't make any sense"* -  [Which is what I said from the very beginning........](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592741/pdo-insert-query-500-server-error#comment74235130_43592741)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yhea and that should solve the problem,

Comment: Sorry for the slow response I left work not long after I posted.
Ill make the changes first thing in morning and mark the answer once ive done it. thanks for everyones help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

I missed the incorrect variable used for the connection being `$dbh` and `$db` in the prepare; *my bad.*

---

Original answer.

This line:

```
if ($dbh->query($sql)) {...}
```

is failing for two reasons:

- Calling [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) on what is already being prepared/executed.
- Using a non-existant variable, `$sql`.

Get rid of that statement with the related brace and replace it with simply and replacing the `$stmt->execute();` with:

```
if($stmt->execute()){

        // success

    } else{

        // error

    }
```

and using PDO's error handling (as you are doing now) and PHP's error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Check your logs also.

Comment: Looks like the Op is allergic in marking answers

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yeah; well not much that can be done about that. *"C'est la vie"* ;-)

Comment: still throwing the same error

Comment: This error is being show in log file
Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /myfile.php on line 13,

Comment: @ChrisYates Ah yeah sorry about that. I missed the wrong variable; I made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem

The above code shows

```
$stmt = $db->prepare
```

Needed to be changed to

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare
```

Thanks for help with the other issue

Quick question how to i insert into a table that has an auto increment column ?